# Why aren't my images resizing with CSS flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm *very* new to coding. I've tried to use CSS flexbox for some images, but they won't change from their default size. Does anyone know why?

here's my code
https://codepen.io/johng003/pen/gOgxKWY

```css
<style>
#donut-gallery{display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-around;
align-items:center;
flex-wrap:wrap;}

#donut1{flex:0 4 150px}
#donut2{flex:1 1 150px}
#donut3{flex:1 4 150px}
#donut4{flex:1 4 150px}
#donut5{flex:1 1 150px}
#donut6{flex:1 1 150px}
</style>
```

```html
<div>  
     <img id="donut1" src="https://i.imgur.com/oXPlX3S.jpg" alt="A donut with galaxy mirror glaze" class="donutimage1">
      <img id="donut2" src="https://i.imgur.com/HOzPDAg.jpg" alt="A donut with cookies and cream filling"class="donutimage2">
      <img id="donut3" src="https://i.imgur.com/ER3hBG4.jpg" alt="An oversized pink sprinkles donut"class="donutimage3">
      <img id="donut4" src="https://i.imgur.com/QfhD5o4.jpg" alt="A tower of colourful donuts"class="donutimage4">
     <img id="donut5" src="https://i.imgur.com/yueQzkr.jpg" alt="A dozen donuts with sprinkles"class="donutimage5">
     <img id="donut6" src="https://i.imgur.com/guK5rGP.jpg" alt="Halloween themed dounuts"class="donutimage6"> 
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice Work

For the `#donut`s, you need a specific or relative width.
The code below can help make sure they are equal. The `calc` method helps make relative dimension division in CSS.

```
#donut1,#donut2, #donut3,#donut4, #donut5, #donut6{width: calc(100% / 6)}
```

Check out media queries and more responsive images
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
https://www.udacity.com/course/responsive-images--ud882

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to set your ID for donut-gallery in HTML.

```css
<style>
#donut-gallery{display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-around;
align-items:center;
flex-wrap:wrap;}

#donut1{flex:0 4 150px}
#donut2{flex:1 1 150px}
#donut3{flex:1 4 150px}
#donut4{flex:1 4 150px}
#donut5{flex:1 1 150px}
#donut6{flex:1 1 150px}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="donut-gallery">  
     <img id="donut1" src="https://i.imgur.com/oXPlX3S.jpg" alt="A donut with galaxy mirror glaze" class="donutimage1">
      <img id="donut2" src="https://i.imgur.com/HOzPDAg.jpg" alt="A donut with cookies and cream filling"class="donutimage2">
      <img id="donut3" src="https://i.imgur.com/ER3hBG4.jpg" alt="An oversized pink sprinkles donut"class="donutimage3">
      <img id="donut4" src="https://i.imgur.com/QfhD5o4.jpg" alt="A tower of colourful donuts"class="donutimage4">
     <img id="donut5" src="https://i.imgur.com/yueQzkr.jpg" alt="A dozen donuts with sprinkles"class="donutimage5">
     <img id="donut6" src="https://i.imgur.com/guK5rGP.jpg" alt="Halloween themed dounuts"class="donutimage6"> 
     </div>
```